# Multiple Except with Same Code to be executed in python: If we use logical OR it does not work any idea why?

Tags: python

Any idea how we can write multiple except on same line as code to be executed for both exceptions is same.

I tried logical OR but it did not work. My code works as expected if I write both exception separately.

```
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open("./file.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(new_data, f, indent=4)

    except ValueError:
        with open("./file.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(new_data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the exception inside brackets ([relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)):

```py
try:
    1 / 0
except (RuntimeError, ZeroDivisionError) as err:
    print("Exception!", err)
```

Prints:

```
Exception! division by zero
```

Comment: It worked. Actually I tried this before posting this question but without () round bracket. Did not knew that except requires tuple for multiple exception in line.

Answer (score 1):

An `except` clause can take multiple exceptions as a parenthesized `tuple`, for example

```
except (FileNotFoundError,ValueError ) as error:
    pass
```

Comment: It worked. Actually I tried this before posting this question but without () round bracket. Did not knew that except requires tuple for multiple exception in line.